# How to disable a dropdownlist based on selection from radio button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Goal:
If the radio button ".... date(s)" is selected then the dropdownlist for start and end date will be NOT disabled.

Problem:
When you have selected and checked the radio button ".... date(s)" and then you press the search button.
The radio button ".... date(s)" is checked but the dropdownlist for start and end date are disabled.

How to enable to make the dropdownlist to be active if ".... date(s)" is checked after you have pressed the search or submit button?

Information:
*If radio button is checked for "All ... only", the dropdownlist for start and end date shall be disabled.

*I'm using boostrap, jquery. asp.net mvc
[image]
CSHTML:

```
                Search for  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectionOfInputRadio, "all", new { id = "test", @class = "positionRadio test-or-dates", @checked = "checked" })
                <label for="all" class="labelPositionForRadio">All ... only</label>

                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectionOfInputRadio, "dates", new { id = "dates", @class = "positionRadio test-or-dates" })
                <label for="dates" class="labelPositionForRadio">date(s)</label>


@{
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.Today;

    List<SelectListItem> myListSelectListItem_YearStartDate = new List<SelectListItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myListSelectListItem_YearStartDate.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = (myDate.Year - i).ToString(), Value = (myDate.Year - i).ToString(), Selected = DateTime.Today.Year == (myDate.Year - i) ? true : false });
    }
}


@Html.DropDownList("YearStartDate", myListSelectListItem_YearStartDate, new { @class = "date-selector", @disabled = "disabled" })

@Html.DropDownList("YearEndDate", myListSelectListItem_YearStartDate, new { @class = "date-selector", @disabled = "disabled" })



@{
    List<SelectListItem> mySelectListItem_month = new List<SelectListItem>();

    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "January", Value = "01", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 1 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "February", Value = "02", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 2 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "March", Value = "03", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 3 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "April", Value = "04", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 4 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "May", Value = "05", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 5 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "June", Value = "06", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 6 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "July", Value = "07", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 7 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "August", Value = "08", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 8 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "September", Value = "09", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 9 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "October", Value = "10", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 10 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "November", Value = "11", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 11 ? true : false });
    mySelectListItem_month.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "December", Value = "12", Selected = DateTime.Today.Month == 12 ? true : false });           
}


@Html.DropDownList("MonthStartDate", mySelectListItem_month, new { @class = "date-selector", @disabled = "disabled" })

@Html.DropDownList("MonthEndDate", mySelectListItem_month, new { @class = "date-selector", @disabled = "disabled" })


@{
    List<SelectListItem> myListSelectListItem_startdate = new List<SelectListItem>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        SelectListItem mySelectListItem_startdate = new SelectListItem();
        mySelectListItem_startdate.Text = i.ToString();
        mySelectListItem_startdate.Value = i.ToString();
        mySelectListItem_startdate.Selected = i.ToString() == DateTime.Today.Day.ToString() ? true : false;

        myListSelectListItem_startdate.Add(mySelectListItem_startdate);
    }
}


@Html.DropDownList("DayStartDate", myListSelectListItem_startdate, new { @class = "date-selector", @disabled = "disabled" })

@Html.DropDownList("DayEndDate", myListSelectListItem_startdate, new { @class = "date-selector", @disabled = "disabled" })


<input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Javascript

```
<script>

    $('.test-or-dates').on('click', function () {
        var _this = $(this);

        var dateSelectors = $('.date-selector');

        if (_this.attr('id') == 'all') {
            dateSelectors.attr('disabled', true);

        }
        else {
            dateSelectors.attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are you doing in the submit method? Are you returning the view or redirecting? You post back the value of `SelectionOfInputRadio` so you should be able to use that to determine if the dropdownlists should be initially enabled or disabled (rather than just setting to to be initially disabled)

Comment: When I press the submit button, you retrieve the data based on the selection from radio type button.